# given this "encryption" function, how can I reverse it and write a decryption function?

Tags: assembly, x86

TL;DR - 1st code just shows what happens before it actually starts doing its thing.Look at the 2nd code, this is what my ASM does to encrypt a string. Look at the 3rd box, it shows the result. Ekey = h. (the code overall is made of C++ and inline assembly)

How can I reverse it back again so it goes back to it's "parent" (original state, before encryption).

---

So I have gotten an assembly code, which encrypts the given string, (body is written in C++, simple cin and couts + for loop to loop each character, nothing serious, but the question applies to assembly)

This is what happens before it goes into encryption routine: (different function)

```asm
push   eax              // Push EAX(Ekey) value to the stack
push   ecx              // Push ECX(character to be encrypted) value to the stack

movzx  ecx, temp_char   // Copies the contents of the temp_char to the ECX register and zero extends the value.
lea    eax, EKey        // Load the address of EKey, into EAX
call   encrypt          // pushes the return address onto the stack and transfers control to a calling label(In this case, it's encrypt). 
mov    temp_char, al    // Copy AL into temp_char variable.

pop    ecx              // Get value from the top of the stack into ECX.
pop    eax              // EAX, gets value from the top of the stack.
```

My encryption routine looks like this: Just to clarify, comments are mine. There's a high chance that they are correct, or some of them might be wrong.(Sorry, I'm still learning)

```asm
        push  ebp                      // Save the old base pointer value.                           
        mov   ebp, esp                 // esp; Set the new base pointer value.                       
        sub   esp, 12                  // Make room for 3 registers          
        push ebx                       // Push EBX value to the stack
        push edx                       // Push EDX value to the stack
        push ecx                       // Push ECX(character to be encrypted) value to the stack
        movzx edx, byte ptr[eax]       // Taking first byte from EAX(Ekey), zero-extending it with 0's , moving that into EDX
        and edx, 0x43                  // Starting from the most significant bit. EDX will be set to 0x00(zeroed out) if 2nd, 7th and 8th bits are 0's. Otherwise if any bits are 1 within the mask, the resulting value will be non-zero

        cmp edx, 0x00                  // See if EDX is equal to 0.
        jnz x16                        // If EDX != 0 go to X16.
        mov edx, 0x07                  // If EDX will be equal to 0, set EDX value to 0x07..
        x16:        inc dl             // Add one to the 'DL' register. Character variable moves up // DL is 1st byte of EDX.
        mov dword ptr[eax], edx        // dword 4 bytes, EDX value into EAX(Ekey) and zero extend it to 4 bytes.
        pop ebx                        // Getting value from the top of the stack, and storing it in the EBX.
        y16 : dec ebx                  // Decrement EBX by 1.
        dec edx                        // Decrement EDX by 1.
        jnz y16                        // If EDX != 0 go to Y16.
        not bl                         // Reverse contents of BL. Such as., (Before 0101, after 1010.) <- Example. So given input will be revesed for encryption purposes. BL, is a 1st byte of EBX.

        pop edx                        // Restores original value of EDX
        mov eax, ebx                   // Move contents from EBX register into EAX(Ekey) register.
        pop ebx                        // Get value from the top of the stack, and then store it in EBX. EAX(Ekey) => EBX.              
        mov  esp, ebp                  // Deallocate local variables                                 
        pop  ebp                       // Restore the caller's base pointer value                    
        ret                            // Gets address from the top of the stack(In this case it's EBX) and returns the value as result. Returning the final result.
```

This is what it does with "soon" string

```asm
 Date: 04/07/2018  Time: 13:53:36

Original string =  soon Hex = 73  6f  6f  6e  

Encrypted string = ÍÒÓÕ Hex = cd  d2  d3  d5
```

I've spent unaccounted hours on this, to get it "reversed" but nothing major came across my mind. The final result, was that I am short of one keyboard. I've already looked up on the internet(this includes stackoverflow) on how to accomplish such goal although I haven't succeeded. So this is my last resort here.

How do I reverse those instructions to get it back to the original string?

Comment: Your function doesn't contain any loops, or any stores to memory.    It only loads 1 byte of input.  How are you calling this?  What calling convention?  You apparently get args in EAX and ECX?  Why is there a `cmp edx, 0` but no `jcc`, `cmovcc`, or `setcc` to read those flags?

Comment: That's broken code. For example, the `cmp edx, 0x00` is unused (result overwritten by `not bl`). Also `bl` is used uninitialized and `ecx` that you claim contains the character to be encrypted isn't even accessed.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I think your "encryption" throws away data, so there is no recovery possible.

Comment: @Jester: fun fact: [`not`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/NOT.html#flags-affected) is one of the few basic ALU instructions that doesn't touch flags.  So it could be a return value for an asm caller...  Or more likely it's just broken.  Anyway, this is sort of like a question missing a [mcve], but worse.

Comment: Ha! Didn't know that.

Comment: @Jester: I'm pretty sure I noticed that while code-golfing.  Or else I wondered why gcc didn't use the ZF result from NOT for something.  Whatever it was, it was weird enough to be memorable.  I think pretty much only NOT and LEA leave flags unmodified, out of legacy ALU instructions x86 got from 8086.  (In practice Skylake's `idiv` doesn't touch flags, either, unfortunately for code-golfing, but the manual says undefined.)

Comment: I've updated the question with full code, sorry for troubles. Although then the results are different too, since it does few extra bits @PeterCordes

Comment: Please replace the nonsense version of the code with the correct one, instead of just adding more at the end.  i.e. make an *edit* to the question, instead of just appending a correction notice, so new readers don't waste time being confused before they get to the correct version of your question.

Comment: But wait, your function still doesn't use ECX, despite the comments saying it's an input.  And your function gets a pointer arg in EAX?  Show the caller for this function, and how you compile.  Is it also asm, passing an arg in EAX?  Or are you compiling a C++ caller with `gcc -m32 -mregparm=2` which uses an EAX, EDX calling convention for the first 2 integer args?  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html

Comment: @PeterCordes I have updated my topic following your guidelines. It should clarify a little bit more. I'm using Visual Studio inline ASM, windows user here :P

Comment: Ok, that wrapper explains the custom calling convention.  (Which is horrible, BTW.  Use function args and return a value in EAX or AL like a normal person, instead of using globals).  @Jester: I just noticed that **the first `pop ebx` is reading the `ecx` function arg that is pushed in the prologue.  Then that stupid loop is a really slow way to do `sub ebx, edx`**  (and set edx to zero as well, but edx isn't being read later).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a C version of your program; I think it makes it pretty self evident how it works:

```
#include <libc.h>
int ec(unsigned char *s, int c) {
    unsigned char y;
    y = *s & 0x43;
    if (y == 0) {
        y = 7;
    }
/*-
  NB: y is in { 7,1,2,3,64,65,66,67 }
*/
    *s = ++y;
    c -= y;
    return ~c & 0xff;
}

void estr(char *s) {
    unsigned char k;
    k = 'h';
    while (*s) {
        *s = ec(&k, *s);
        s++;
    }
}

int main() {
    char p[20];
    strcpy(p, "Hello, world!");
    printf("%s\n", p);
    estr(p);
    printf("%s\n", p);
    estr(p);
    printf("%s\n", p);
}
```

There are two things going on here; the first is the key sequence.  The key starts from a given seed value (‘H’ = 0x48).  Which generates the sequence: 0x41,0x42,0x43,0x44,0x41,.... by the operation key = (key AND 0x43)+1; note the weird exception for 0 in the code.

This sequence is applied to each character by the encryption function: c = NOT (c - key).  This function is its own inverse, thus if you apply it to plain text, it yields encrypted text and visa versa.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I hope that helps, I'm not sure! I will need to spend a bit in C field, to get used to it, although that shouldn't be hard, so I assumed you have resolved my problem ;) Thank you again :P

Comment: I'm still in a blind spot :(, can't really disguise what's it doing. Can't debug, as I'm compiling using DEV CMD PROMPT VS2017 and it doesn't have debugger for C(at least it complies)

Comment: Thanks, I presume my problem is solved. You've supplied me sufficient amount of information which should be sufficient for myself in-order to solve this riddle. Although that doesn't work, perhaps starting at the glaring screen for the next 4 hours will bring me some kind of miracle !